# Laravel Ajax File Upload not recieving data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a ajax form that sends a bunch of data to my conroller, but when I add

```
processData: false, // important
contentType: false, // important
```

To my ajax call Laravel receives an empty array in my controller with: `$data = Input::all();`

Heres the whole ajax call if you want to see it:

```
    var ImagesData = new FormData();
    ImagesData.append('pictureFile', $('input').get(0).files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/a/item/create',
        data: ImagesData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // important
        contentType: false, // important
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Input::file($key)`. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files) part of the documentation.

```
$file = Input::file('pictureFile');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set

```
processData: false, // important
contentType: false, // important
```

you need to create new form with javascript form standard.

```
var ImagesData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```